# C#: Retrieve all the keys from a dictionary that match a criteria

Tags: c#, dictionary, pattern-matching, iteration

.net 4.5.2

My dictionary is defined in this way:

```
Dictionary<string, string> Dates = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

and it contains keys in this format:

```
2016/4/23
2016/4/24
2016/4/25
2016/4/26
2016/3/1
2016/3/2
```

How can I iterate over all the keys in my dictionary that have this format:

```
2016/4/*
```

Comment: It will be great if you post some code that u have tried.

Comment: you can do `foreach(var key in Dates.Keys)`

Comment: Yes, I can do that but I'm looking for some functionality in C# that could be used for these situations. Some thing like LINQ for selective searching and matching

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what you are using dates in String type instead of using DateTime type.

Anyway, to answer to your question just use StartsWith extension methods like this:

```
var aprilMonthKeys = Dates.Keys.Where(k => k.StartsWith("2016/4/"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
foreach(var record in Dates.Where(r => r.Key.Contains("2016/4/")))
{
    // Do something.....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I iterate over all the keys in my dictionary

You could use `Keys` property of the dictionary to loop through each `Key`.

```
foreach(string key in Dates.Keys)
{
    var date = DateTime.ParseExact(key, "yyyy/M/d", null);
    if(date.Year == 2016 && date.Month == 4)
    {
         // logic
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could also use `Linq`

```
    var filtered = dictionary.Keys.Where(k=> 
    {           
        var date = DateTime.ParseExact(k, "yyyy/M/d", null);            
        return date.Year == 2016 && date.Month == 4;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just loop through all items checking if the key contains the substring "2016/4/" and save the keys in another list.

```
List<string> keys= new List<string>();

foreach(var item in Dates)
{
    if (item.Key.Contains("2016/4/")
        keys.Add(item.Key);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter the dictionary with specified Year and Month then you can do:

```
var filteredDates =  Dates.Where(d =>
                DateTime.ParseExact(d.Key, "yyyy/MM/dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Year == 2016 &&
                DateTime.ParseExact(d.Key, "yyyy/MM/dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Month == 4).ToDictionary(d=>d.Key);
```

This will give you filtered dictionary containing days for 2016/04